# Find the radius and the interval of convergence of the given power series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

> Find the radius and the interval of convergence of the power series
> $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(x+1)^{3n}}{(n+1)\times8^{n}}.$$

I believe the first step should be a root test which gives
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{(x+1)^{3}}{8\times(n+1)} = \frac{ (x+1)^{3}}{8} \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{(n+1)} $$
I am stuck here I know that the limit should be less than zero in this case it is always 0 not depending on x, does this mean the radius is infinity?

Comment: You are not studying the correct limit for the root test.

Comment: When you have a series of the type $\sum_n a_n x^n$ you need for the root test to look at the sequence of the $|a_n|^{\frac{1}{n}}$s. You do not include any $x$.

Comment: Taking the $n$th root gives $\frac{(x+1)^3}{8\sqrt[n]{n+1}}$.